# in NDK development, how to ignore the system header file and libs?

Tags: android-ndk, include

When building under NDK environment, the system-specific include and lib path

`platforms/android-X/arch-arm/usr/include/`  and

`platforms/android-X/arch-arm/usr/lib`  was added automatically.

I'm trying to use my version of the libraries and headers, What should I do in `Android.mk?` to avoid `ndk` add those path automatically?